# PyCharm can't install Pyautogui

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyautogui

I have been using IDLE up til recently after reading Al Sweigart's book but have moved to using PyCharm as was recommended by a colleague. I cannot install PyAutoGUI with a 3.8 interpreter. I have it working in IDLE where I installed it from the command line. I also have it working in a Python 2.7 interpreter in PyCharm that came bundled with ArcMap. I have Pip currently installed in PyCharm at 19.0.3 I tried the latest version 20.0.2 and that failed, I managed to install openpyxl in PyCharm with pip 19.0.3 but can't do pillow, pyscreeze or pyautogui.

When I try to install it in the 3.8 interpreter I have in PyCharm I get this error:

```
Collecting PyAutoGUI
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/3c/4711a718371f6a16fd19833abf5feea2b1701722bcecdba782d5db7a9f36/PyAutoGUI-0.9.48.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pymsgbox in c:\users\brentond\documents\venv\lib\site-packages (from PyAutoGUI) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: PyTweening>=1.0.1 in c:\users\brentond\documents\venv\lib\site-packages (from PyAutoGUI) (1.0.3)
Collecting pyscreeze>=0.1.21 (from PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/7d/a0e85da28a96e2ff2f39e682ff84eb92501b564883fde87d92aee29966a2/PyScreeze-0.1.26.tar.gz
Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5 (from PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/8b/f1a396f8ec5923e11246fabe29419a6dd8949a0360337fe6ad0f28a9c33b/PyGetWindow-0.0.8.tar.gz
Collecting mouseinfo (from PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/dd/dd184693becfcf4fe3eda41462b791687fd4b1d314f53b387a72d88ba08d/MouseInfo-0.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting Pillow>=6.2.1 (from pyscreeze>=0.1.21->PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/47/f28067b187dd664d205f75b07dcc6e0e95703e134008a14814827eebcaab/Pillow-7.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyrect (from pygetwindow>=0.0.5->PyAutoGUI)
Collecting pyperclip (from mouseinfo->PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/0f/4eda562dffd085945d57c2d9a5da745cfb5228c02bc90f2c74bbac746243/pyperclip-1.7.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: Pillow, pyscreeze, pyrect, pygetwindow, pyperclip, mouseinfo, PyAutoGUI
  Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
    Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command "C:\Users\brentond\My Documents\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\brentond\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-svq1di4m\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\brentond\My Documents\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow":
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 852, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Users\brentond\My Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\brentond\My Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 687, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py", line 907, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



    ----------------------------------------

Command ""C:\Users\brentond\My Documents\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\brentond\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-svq1di4m\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\brentond\My Documents\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\
```

Grateful for any pointers, I am new to this. Thank you

Comment: Check this link https://www.itread01.com/content/1540738629.html

Comment: Hi thanks for looking at it. I tried installing pillow from PyCharm and that failed. I have it all working in IDLE and in a different interpreter, it is just when i try to install with python 3.8.